# UISearchController does not recognise umlaut, Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a search function in my app but it does not recognise any umlaut (ä,ö,ü). I use UISearchController. How do I adjust the code that it recognises umlaut?

```
($0.title as AnyObject).contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
```

Comment: Why is title being cast as AnyObject? I'm assuming it's a String or NSString type. You're going to have an easier time using either of those data types.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but has no impact on the umlaut

Comment: The umlaut isn't your problem, it's applying contains() to incongruous types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me. I would sanity check your strings in lldb.

```
  func search() {
    let stringWithDiaeresis = "Reënter"
    let stringWithoutDiaeresis = "Reenter"
    let searchStringWithDiaeresis = "Reë"
    let searchStringWithoutDiaeresis = "Ree"

    if stringWithDiaeresis.contains(searchStringWithDiaeresis) {
      print("Range of Reë detected in Reënter")
    }

    if stringWithDiaeresis.contains(searchStringWithoutDiaeresis) {
      print("Range of Reë detected in Reenter")
    }

    if stringWithoutDiaeresis.contains(searchStringWithDiaeresis) {
      print("Range of Reë detected in Reenter")
    }

    if stringWithoutDiaeresis.contains(searchStringWithoutDiaeresis) {
      print("Range of Ree detected in Reenter")
    }

    /* Prints the following:
     Range of Reë detected in Reënter
     Range of Ree detected in Reenter
     */

    if (stringWithDiaeresis as AnyObject).contains(searchStringWithDiaeresis) {
      print("Reënter contains Reë")
    }

    if (stringWithDiaeresis as AnyObject).contains(searchStringWithoutDiaeresis) {
      print("Reënter contains Ree")
    }

    if (stringWithoutDiaeresis as AnyObject).contains(searchStringWithDiaeresis) {
      print("Reenter contains Reë")
    }

    if (stringWithoutDiaeresis as AnyObject).contains(searchStringWithoutDiaeresis) {
      print("Reenter contains Ree")
    }

    /* Prints the following:
     Reënter contains Reë
     Reenter contains Ree
     */
  }
```

If your intention is to match strings with diacritics to those without, you're going to need to sanitize your data and remove diacritics from everything.

E.g.

```
if stringWithDiaeresis.localizedStandardContains(searchStringWithoutDiaeresis) {
  print("Reënter contains Ree")
}

/* Prints the following:
 Reënter contains Ree
 */
```

The moral of the story here is that you really ought to be using the specialized/more sophisticated methods available to String types instead of generic contains().